# Calculation error creating ggplot2 stat extension

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a ggplot2 extension. I'd like to create a stat (or geom) that allows me to plot well logs in a fashion somewhat similar to this [well log image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohrprofil#/media/Datei:Bohrprofil.jpg). The calculation encapsulated in the ggproto object eventually fails though.
Let's look at the pet example! Suppose we have some well log information giving us the lower boundary of a geological unit, its name and a position indicator:

```
library(tidyverse) 
testwell <- tibble::tribble(
  ~depth,    ~type, ~pos,
  3,        "loam",    1,
  7,        "sand",    1,
  7.5,      "clay",    1,
  11,       "murl",    1,
  12.2,   "gravel",    1
)
```

In order to transform this into plotable polygons I created a ggproto object and a stat.

```
StatGeostack <- ggproto("StatGeostack", Stat,
                        required_aes = c("x", "y", "group"),
                        compute_group = function(data, scales, params, glvl = 0){
                          bound_low <- data$y
                          strata <-  data$group
                          position <- data$x

# x-position doesn't really matter for now so let's just jitter it a bit
# and pretend we have a drillcore diameter of "1" so we can draw polygons
                          xmin <- position[1]-0.5   
                          xmax <- position[1]+0.5 

#The lower boundary of the first strata is the upper boundary of the second and so on
                          bound_up <- c(glvl, bound_low)
                          length(bound_up) <- length(bound_low)

# This tibble contains all the information alas not in the right format
                          stackframe <- tibble::tibble(
                            strata = strata,
                            bound_up = bound_up,
                            bound_low = bound_low
                          )

# adapt input format for ggplot2 polygons
                          purrr::pmap_dfr(stackframe,
                                          function(strata, bound_up, bound_low, xmin, xmax){
                                            tibble::tibble(y = c(rep(bound_up, times = 2),
                                                                 rep(bound_low, times = 2)),
                                                           x = c(xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin),
                                                           group = rep(strata, times = 4))
                                          },
                                          xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax)
                          }
                        )

#creating the stat corresponding to the ggproto object
stat_geostack <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                          position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                          inherit.aes = TRUE, glvl = 0, ...){
  layer(
    stat = StatGeostack, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, glvl = 0, ...)
  )
}
```

So this is what I came up with. To see why I'm not happy with the result, let's use the new stat in a plot

```
ggplot(data = testwell, 
             aes(x = pos, y = depth*-1, group = type)) +
  stat_geostack(aes(fill = type)) +
  theme_bw()
```

The result looks like this. On first glance this doesn't look too bad, but then again half of our stratigraphy is missing. It's in the legend but not drawn in the panel.
[image: the resulting plot]

I tried to figure out what is going on by changing from "fill" to "color"

```
ggplot(data = testwell, 
                   aes(x = pos, y = depth*-1, group = type)) +
  stat_geostack(fill = NA, aes(color = type), size = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: hollow drill log]

So what apparently happens is that the missing stratigraphic units aren't gone but hidden behind each other. The reason for this seems to be, that each polygon has its upper boundary set to zero, while the lower boundary is calculated as intended. The calculation-mechanism I used inside the ggproto's "calculate_group" function works just fine in the global environment. I can calculate the polygon vertices outside the ggplot2 extension mechanism and than make a regular ggplot2+geom_polygon plot with no problem, but that's not what I want to do.

Thank you for staying with me in this somewhat exhausting post.

Comment: It looks like this bit of code `bound_up <- c(glvl, bound_low)` sets the bound_up that defaults to 0 if `glvl` is not specified. Since you don't specify `glvl` in your ggplot call, it will be 0. Should `glvl` maybe be a calculated instead passed around variable? (And is the reason it works outside the stat because you have a meaningful `glvl` in your environment?)

Comment: The `glvl` does not seem to be the problem. Even if I remove it completely and hardwire everything, the problem persists. In fact, even setting the `bound_up` to fixed values doesn't help. Something seems fundamentally incorrect with the way I try to run the calculation.

Comment: The data associated with each colour / fill strata is treated as a separate group for the purpose of `compute_group`, so I don't really understand what is supposed to happen around "The lower boundary of the first strata is the upper boundary of the second and so on". What you are describing sounds like a regular stacked barchart that can be produced with `geom_col()`, or am I missing something that requires a polygon approach?